# how use custom joomla date in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, joomla

i have this query from a custom class in Joomla which uses CURDATE and NOW.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT catid FROM table_x WHERE DATE(publish_up)=CURDATE() AND publish_up<=NOW()";
```

default server time had to change so i want to change it to use joomla custom time called from here:

```
$date = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
```

i hoped it whould be easy (since i am kinda nooby) like

```
....WHERE DATE(publish_up)='".$date."' AND ....
```

but it doesn't work
any ideas?

Comment: In mysql date literals should be in `'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss'` format. Format your date output to comply with this format.

Comment: so you mean create a second variable to format $date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL CURDATE() and NOW() use different formats 
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_curdate.asp
so if you want compare them with your date you need to prepare it right

Please take a look at example code below

```
$nowdate = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin')); // 2016-08-23 15:01:14
$curdate = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->format('Y-m-d'); // 2016-08-23
```

for Joomla older then v3.3 you should use

```
$curdate = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->toFormat('Y-m-d'); // 2016-08-23
```

then you can build query using JDatabase

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query->select("distinct ". $db->quoteName('id'));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__content'));
$query->where($db->quoteName('publish_up') .' <= '. $db->quote( $nowdate )); //today and older
$query->where('Date('.$db->quoteName('publish_up').')' . ' = '.  $db->quote( $curdate )); // today
$query->order('id ASC');

$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadRowList();
print_r($rows);
```

Please take a look at JDate documentation 
https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_use_JDate

Comment: thank you very much. that was really helpful. there seems to be a restriction with the Joomla API though or i am missing something. As soon as ->format('Y-m-d') is used, the date returns to UTC. if use a different format like getDate('now +2 hour')->format('Y-m-d'), it works ok. is there another way instead of new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin') ??

Comment: Joomla by default save and use time as UFC, and think this format i used when you call getDate.
You can also change default timezone at Global Configuration > Server > TimeZone and then call eg.
from global configuration
$config = JFactory::getConfig();
$offset = $config->get('offset');
$timezone = new DateTimeZone( $offset );
$date = new JDate();
$date->setTimezone($timezone); echo $date;

or from user setup
$timezone = new DateTimeZone( JFactory::getUser()->getParam('timezone') );
$date = new JDate();
$date->setTimezone($timezone);
echo $date;

Comment: Thanx again for your help.Using the global timezone is an even better idea. Still the same though. I can't format $curdate for the query to read it as Y-m-d. i add `$curdate->format('Y-M-d');` but it returns it to UTC. the only situation where format works is on an echo. `echo $curdate->format('Y-M-d');` but this is useless since i need it formated before the query

Comment: what i am saying is  `$curdate = JFactory::getDate('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'))->format('Y-m-d');` doesn't work. it returns formatted UTC no matter the timezone.

Comment: Your right :) please try to use this, i'm sure this will help.
$date->format('Y-m-d', TRUE);
2nd parameter switch between UTC and local timezone.